# How to bind newly loaded forms with ajax action in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the form and its submitting ok with jquery ajax.

Now i am trying to load the form insdie lightbox , then form submits normally .

How can i make that all forms with specific class should be submitted via ajax even if they are loaded dynamically

Comment: I have this code `$(".form").ajaxForm(options);` , how can i use `on` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest implementation is to rebind the events after the form is appended to the target $dom node

UPDATE: to your latest comment, just init `$(".form").ajaxForm(options);` again AFTER you appended the elements dynamically.